# Thread 1: Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value. Getting image from Gallery swift

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, image-processing, uiimageview

I am trying to get an image from the gallery through a button but I am getting this error:

> Thread 1: Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an
>   Optional value.

I have looked at all the other questions that are
similar to mine, but for some reason, I am not able to solve my
problem.

````
class ViewController: UIViewController, VNDocumentCameraViewControllerDelegate,  UINavigationControllerDelegate, UIImagePickerControllerDelegate  {

    var textRecognitionRequest = VNRecognizeTextRequest()
    var recognizedText = ""
    var text2 = "";

    @IBOutlet weak var imageTest: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet weak var centreView: CardView!
    @IBOutlet weak var centreViewBorder: UIView!
    @IBOutlet weak var circleButton: UIButton!



    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        imageTest = UIImageView()
```

```
IBAction func uploadImage(_ sender: UIButton) {
        let imagePicker = UIImagePickerController()
        imagePicker.delegate = self
        imagePicker.sourceType = .photoLibrary
        self.present(imagePicker, animated: true, completion: nil)

    }
   func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [UIImagePickerController.InfoKey : Any]) {
        guard let image = info[.originalImage] as? UIImage else {
            fatalError("Error")
        }
        imageTest!.image = image
    dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)

    }
func imagePickerControllerDidCancel(_ picker: UIImagePickerController) {
    dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
}
````

Comment: At what time do you get crash? when button press or after image choose?

Comment: After image is choosen

Comment: occurs at line:   imageTest!.image = image

Comment: it means your imageTest image view is nil.(missing). make sure that image view bind to the view controller correctly

Comment: it is connected though

Comment: Why are you assigning imageTest to a new instance of UIImageView in your viewDidLoad? When you declare a view with type ending in a "!" the variable points to a nil value in memory, no need to assign it to another instance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first issue is you are switching your imageTest variable to a different instance of UIImageView. Remember, when you declare an IBOutlet and use a ! your variable's memory pointer references a nil value in memory. You no longer need to assign it again. Additionally, when referenced in the future it will no longer need to be unwrapped because the ! in the declaration makes the force unwrap explicit.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        imageTest = UIImageView()  -- ***** Remove this line *****
```

Also, this needs to be changed

```
   func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [UIImagePickerController.InfoKey : Any]) {
        guard let image = info[.originalImage] as? UIImage else {
            fatalError("Error")
        }
        imageTest!.image = image -- ******* REMOVE THE BANG HERE ******
    dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)

    }
```